# Entity Framework Core - I can't add a new migration since I added a new table (Unable to resolve service)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, migration, database-migration, dbcontext

I am facing a problem since I added a new table to my DbContext: I cannot add a new migration.

I have 42 tables in my DbContext and the migrations were working fine until I added the 42nd one.
When I use the "Add-Migration migrationName" command, I always get the following error:

`

```
PM> Add-Migration promocode -verbose
Using project 'CommercatorCMS'.
Using startup project 'CommercatorCMS'.
Build started...
Build succeeded.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --depsfile H:\Dev\CommercatorCMS\bin\Debug\net6.0\CommercatorCMS.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\DYLAN-PC\.nuget\packages --runtimeconfig H:\Dev\CommercatorCMS\bin\Debug\net6.0\CommercatorCMS.runtimeconfig.json C:\Users\DYLAN-PC\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\6.0.8\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll migrations add promocode --json --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly H:\Dev\CommercatorCMS\bin\Debug\net6.0\CommercatorCMS.dll --project H:\Dev\CommercatorCMS\CommercatorCMS.csproj --startup-assembly H:\Dev\CommercatorCMS\bin\Debug\net6.0\CommercatorCMS.dll --startup-project H:\Dev\CommercatorCMS\CommercatorCMS.csproj --project-dir H:\Dev\CommercatorCMS\ --language C# --configuration Debug --working-dir H:\Dev\CommercatorCMS --root-namespace CommercatorCMS --nullable
Using assembly 'CommercatorCMS'.
Using startup assembly 'CommercatorCMS'.
Using application base 'H:\Dev\CommercatorCMS\bin\Debug\net6.0'.
Using working directory 'H:\Dev\CommercatorCMS'.
Using root namespace 'CommercatorCMS'.
Using project directory 'H:\Dev\CommercatorCMS\'.
Remaining arguments: .
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider in assembly 'CommercatorCMS'...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
Using environment 'Development'.
Using application service provider from Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Found DbContext 'CommercatorContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'CommercatorContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[CommercatorCMS.Business.Data.CommercatorContext]' while attempting to activate 'CommercatorCMS.Business.Data.CommercatorContext'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Unable to create an object of type 'CommercatorContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

`

I thought it was my table that was the problem, so I replaced it with a basic class ("Test") containing only a primary key and a string property. But that doesn't work either.
If I remove this last table, the migrations work correctly...

Is there anything I don't know about?
Is there a maximum number of tables that can be accepted ? (I don't think so...)

Thank you for your help and for your time !

Here is the DbContext :

```
using CommercatorCMS.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace CommercatorCMS.Business.Data
{
    public class CommercatorContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Website> Websites { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WebsiteModule> WebsiteModules { get; set; }
        public DbSet<News> News { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PageTitle> PageTitles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PageSection> PageSections { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PageSectionMedia> PageSectionMedias { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PageContent> PageContents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserNotification> UserNotifications { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Media> Medias { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductMedia> ProductMedia { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductDescription> ProductDescriptions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductLabel> ProductLabels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Roles> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderHistory> OrderHistories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderState> OrderStates { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderContent> OrderContents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tickets> Tickets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TicketProduct> TicketProducts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Wishlist> Wishlist { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WishlistCustomer> WishlistCustomers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WishlistProducts> WishlistProducts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CategoryLabel> CategoriesLabels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Color> Colors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Size> Sizes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SizeLabel> SizeLabels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ColorLabel> ColorLabels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Birthlist> Birthlists { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BirthlistProduct> BirthlistProducts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BirthlistCustomer> BirthlistCustomers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Test> PromoCodes { get; set; } // ← Problem is HERE

        public CommercatorContext()
        {

        }

        public CommercatorContext(DbContextOptions<CommercatorContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
#if DEBUG
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost\\MSSQLSERVER01;Database=CommercatorCMS;Trusted_Connection=True;"); //Local
#else
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=???.???.???.???,???,???;Initial Catalog=???????;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=???;Password=???;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;"); //Prod
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Test.cs :

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CommercatorCMS.Models
{
    public class Test
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the CSPROJ :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Business\Tools\" />
    <Folder Include="Migrations\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="JsonWebToken" Version="1.9.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.8">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="Views\WebPages\Index.cshtml">
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I have two questions. 1. what is your startup project? 2. which project is set as the default project in the package manager console?

Comment: The connection string is failing.  Either you are not in DEBUG or the database doesn't exist.  You can use SQL Server Management Studio and test the connection string.  Make sure the server\instance in the SSMS login window matches the connection string.  Then test the database by making a query to same database.  Finally you can check the logs in the explorer under Management.  There should be an error at time you tried to run the c# code.

Comment: @viveknuna I have only one project in my solution. The name is "CommercatorCMS" and that is the one that is selected in the package manager console. This is also my startup project. 
Also, my project compile without any erros and start without problems

Comment: @jdweng My connection string is the same that I use since the begining of the project, and the add-migration is working if I delete the last table "public DbSet<Test> PromoCodes { get; set; } ". I looked in the logs of sql server but nothing related to this problem...

Comment: SQL Server you cannot delete a column of an existing table.  You must drop the table and then add table with missing column.

Comment: @jdweng The table has not been added, because the add-migration don't work. When I say that I delete the last table in the context, I mean commenting the line with DbSet<Test>

Comment: Do you see a connection in the SQL logs?  The error indicates you cannot create a table.   If a table exists than you cannot add the same table.  Maybe it is the primary key.  The SSMS should show the error unless it is the Migration that is giving the error.  Did you view the database model in VS?

Comment: @jdweng While checking the database model, I realized that there was a problem with a link in my database... The migration started working right after I fixed it ... I am not sure what was the cause, but it seems to work now.  Thank you a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use VS 2019, you need to have the 2019 version installed

Answer (score 0):

Try change your connection string, adding "Encrypt:False". By default the value is True. Could be something about the connection with your database.